Восстановление RAID1 на сервере Lenovo System x3650 M5
Вывалился диск. Рейд в данный момент в статусе Degraded.
Подкинул новый диск, но в биосе не нашел rebuild
подскажите, как на этом сервере восстановить raid ?
